# self-loop labeling problem using EditableGraph

Tags: python, graph, netgraph

I plan to use `EditableGraph` of `Netgraph` as the foundation of my application. However, I have encountered the following issue. Let us consider the following program that draws a small graph.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netgraph import  EditableGraph
from numpy import array
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
editgraph = EditableGraph([(0,1),(0,2),(2,2)],
                          node_label_fontdict=dict(size=9),
                          node_labels=True,
                          edge_width=2,
                          node_layout= {0: array([0.5, 0.5]), 1: array([0.25, 0.5]), 2: array([0.75, 0.5])},
                          ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

If:

1. I create a self loop on node 1 (i.e. edge (1,1) );
2. I add a label on this loop;
3. The label cannot be added and I have the error message below:

```
Initiated writing label(s).
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\netgraph\_main.py:1082: UserWarning: Plotting of edge labels for self-loops not supported for straight edges.
Ignoring edge with label: 
  warnings.warn(msg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 298, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\netgraph\_interactive_variants.py", line 518, in _on_key_press
    self._edit_labels(event.key)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\netgraph\_interactive_variants.py", line 550, in _edit_labels
    self._edit_edge_label(artist, key)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\netgraph\_interactive_variants.py", line 571, in _edit_edge_label
    self._edit_text_object(self.edge_label_artists[edge], key)
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
KeyError: (1, 1)
```

The resulting graph is as follows:

[image: Resulting graph]
**However when**:

1. I first add a label to the self loop (2,2);
2. Then I create the self-loop (1,1);
3. I can label the self-loop (1,1) normally !?

Moreover, I have not encountered any problems with edges that are not self-loops.

What is the problem with this example that prevents adding a label to a new self-loop? Why does labeling the existing self-loop enable the possibility to label the created self-loop?
How can this issue be fixed? It would be helpful to be able to label the self-loop using `EditableGraph` regardless of the protocol used.

Comment: That very much looks like a bug. I can't look into it right now, but I will do so early next week. If you could submit this issue to the [Netgraph issue tracker](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph/issues), then I definitely won't forget.

Comment: Thanks ! This prevents to fully use it. I have submitted this isssue to Netgraph issue tracker.  I have another question how can I resize EditableGraph to fully occupy the figure?

Comment: Try out these suggestions [here](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph/issues/42).

Comment: [This bug](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph/issues/84) should now be resolved on the dev branch.